# Filtering results by reviewing multiple values for single column

Tags: sql

I have a table that has data by the account for each device is associated to the account:

```
account_id  |  model
1           |   iPhone
1           |   Samsung 
2           |   iPhone
3           |   Samsung
4           |   iPhone
4           |   Samsung
4           |   LG
```

I am trying to create a query in which i collect the account ids that fall into one of the following buckets:  iPhone *only*, Samsung *only*, or iPhone and Samsung.

In this example, they would want account id #4 to fall into the bucket of iPhone and Samsung.

So far my results are producing overlap which will cause query issues.

Any assistance on how I should structure my query(ies) to produce these results would be helpful

Thank you,
  Danielle

Comment: Please add some example data. A few rows will help.

Comment: I think you might have left out the sample data you meant to include (what is account id #4). Also, please tag your DBMS. Here's a good guide to asking good SQL questions: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick replies. Due to privacy reasons I can only share what is in the email as an example of how the data is structured.  This is not the real data just example of how it does look. The table inputs a row for each device associated to an account number.  So basically the account number will be listed multiple times depending on how many devices are associated with it.  account_id is integer field and model is VARCHAR and they exist in the same table.  The account id #4 is equal to account id = 4 which has a Samsung, iPhone, and LG devices associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
select account_id  
from tables
group by account_id  
having count(distinct model)=1
```

Example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/146a533/1

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes your DBMS supports windowed functions. If this is not the case, tag your DBMS. It'll be more complicated.

```
SELECT TD1.*,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN model = 'Samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY account_id) = 1
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN model <> 'Samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY account_id) = 0 THEN 'Samsung Only'
            WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN model = 'iPhone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY account_id) = 1
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN model <> 'iPhone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY account_id) = 0 THEN 'iPhone Only'
            WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN model = 'iPhone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY account_id) = 1
             AND MAX(CASE WHEN model = 'Samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY account_id) = 1 THEN 'iPhone and Samsung'
            ELSE 'Other'                   
        END AS Product_Tag
  FROM TEST_DATA;
```

Edit: If your DBMS supports CTE's it's not too bad either ...

```
WITH TAGGED 
  ( SELECT Account_ID,
           SUM(CASE WHEN model = 'Samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Samsung_Count,
           SUM(CASE WHEN model = 'iPhone' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS iPhone_Count,
           SUM(CASE WHEN model NOT IN ('iPhone','Samsung') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Neither_Count
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Account_ID,
                            model
              FROM TEST_DATA
           ) TMP
     GROUP
        BY Account_ID
  )
SELECT TD1.*,
       'Samsung Only'
  FROM TEST_DATA TD1
 WHERE EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM Tagged
            WHERE Samsung_Count = 1
              AND iPhone_Count = 0
              AND Neither_Count = 0
              AND Tagged.account_id = TD1.account_id
         )
 UNION
SELECT TD1.*,
       'iPhone Only'
  FROM TEST_DATA TD1
 WHERE EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM Tagged
            WHERE Samsung_Count = 0
              AND iPhone_Count = 1
              AND Neither_Count = 0
              AND Tagged.account_id = TD1.account_id
         ) 
 UNION
SELECT TD1.*,
       'iPhone and Samsung Only'
  FROM TEST_DATA TD1
 WHERE EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM Tagged
            WHERE Samsung_Count = 1
              AND iPhone_Count = 1
              AND Neither_Count = 0
              AND Tagged.account_id = TD1.account_id
         );
```

If it doesn't support either ... it's not pretty

```
SELECT TD1.*,
       'Samsung Only'
  FROM TEST_DATA TD1
 WHERE TD1.model = 'Samsung'
   AND NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM TEST_DATA TD2
            WHERE TD1.model <> TD2.model
         )
 UNION        
SELECT TD1.*,
       'iPhone Only'
  FROM TEST_DATA TD1
 WHERE TD1.model = 'iPhone'
   AND NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM TEST_DATA TD2
            WHERE TD1.model <> TD2.model
         )
 UNION    
SELECT TD1.*,
       'Samsung and iPhone'
  FROM TEST_DATA TD1
 WHERE EXISTS 
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM (SELECT account_id,
                          SUM
                            ( CASE WHEN model = 'iPhone' THEN 1
                                   WHEN model = 'Samsung' THEN 1
                                   ELSE 0
                               END
                            ) AS product_agg
                     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                                  account_id,
                                  model
                             FROM TEST_DATA
                          ) TMP
                  ) TMP2
            WHERE TMP2.product_agg = 2
              AND TD1.account_id = TMP2.account_id
         )
   AND NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT 1
             FROM TEST_DATA TD2
            WHERE TD2.model NOT IN ('iPhone','Samsung')
              AND TD2.account_id = TD1.account_id
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions in the `HAVING` clause to verify the conditions.

```
select account_id  
from tablename
group by account_id  
having count(case when model = 'iPhone' then 1 end) = count(*)   -- #1 Only iPhones
    or count(case when model = 'Samsung' then 1 end) = count(*)  -- #2 Only Samsung
    or count(distinct case when model in ('iPhone', 'Samsung') then model end) = 2 -- #3 both of them
```

Explanation:

1) - count of iPhone is the same as total count, i.e. only iPhones.

2) - count of Samsung is the same as total count, i.e. only Samsungs.

3) - count of distinct iPhone and Samsung is 2, i.e. both iPhone and Samsung.